# What is the true name for Kyubey?

Tags: madoka-magica

Through out the series the Magical Girls call it *Kyubey* however they respond just as well to Homura when she calls them *Incubator* and don't go to correct her.

I am wondering which is their real name, Kyubey or Incubator?

Comment: "Kyubey" is a kind of short-hand for "In(cub)ator"; perhaps like any other shortened name or nickname, e.g. Edward -> "Ed". _Kyubey_ could be seen as the creatures' names, whereas _Incubator_ is the name of the species/entity, whereas you and I are _human_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name *Kyubey* is a short-hand for In*cub*ator (pronounced [in-**ky*uh*-bey**-ter]<sup>[(source)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incubator)</sup>, which shows similar phonetic pronunciations). This follows a pattern similar to other nicknames or names that are shortened, such as:

- "Ed", from "Edward" (e.g. [Edward "Ed" Elric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fullmetal_Alchemist_characters#Edward) from FMA) and
- "Al", from "Alphonse" (like [Alphonse "Al" Elric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fullmetal_Alchemist_characters#Alphonse), also from FMA).

That said, ***Kyubey* is the name of the creatures**, whereas ***Incubator* is its race/species**.

From the [Madoka Magica wiki](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Kyubey#Personality):

> Kyubey is an Incubator/Messenger of Magic. Because of this, he, like his race, cannot exhibit emotions of any kind.

In [episode 8](http://www.crunchyroll.com/puella-magi-madoka-magica/episode-8-i-was-stupid-so-stupid-591749), around 20:10, Homura says

> I won't let things go according to your plans, Kyubey.
>
> Or should I say... "Incubator"?

Which would be equivalent, in context, to me saying

> I won't let things go according to your plans, Memor-X.
>
> Or should I say... "Human"?

Comment: More like "Eddy" from "Edward".